# Is there an impact of type spec on generated code?

Tags: elixir

I'm doing some excises based on the 99-Problems list. For P01 which purpose is to find the last element of a list, my implementation  is almost always outperformed by `List.last/1` while being the same. The difference is about 20% but there is quite a lot of variations between executions (sometimes more than 100%). Tests are done on a freshly restarted VM and functions are called 10, 100 and 1000 on a list of one million elements.

This is my implementation:

```
def p01([]), do: nil
def p01([h]), do: h
def p01([_ | r]), do: p01(r)
```

A closer look at  `List.last/1` source shows however 2 differences

1. The compiler directive `@compile :inline_list_funcs` which I understand being an Erlang directive only applying on the current module. I'm not sure if it  has a real impact on my short piece of code
2. The type specification `@spec last([elem]) :: nil | elem when elem: var`

These two changes made the execution times of my implementation closer much more often to the ones of  `List.last/1`.

**Q1**: Does the compiler use `@spec...` to optimize the code somehow ?

**Q2**: side question : in my tests, the erlang standard library function `:lists.last/1` does always better than `List.last/1`. Again there are are some variations between two runs but the difference is quite stable. Why isn't `List.last/1` a simple wrapper around the Erlang implementation ?

Comment: fwiw the official code for `List.last/1` is here https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6.5/lib/elixir/lib/list.ex#L244

Comment: I'm pretty sure `@spec` doesn't change codegen. What's the performance if you only do the first change (@compile)?

Comment: Re: why not a wrapper, probably because `lists:last` throws an error for empty lists while `List.last` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about question #2, but re: question #1, from the elixir docs: "type specifications are never used by the compiler to optimize or modify code", see: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html